# High quality audio recording in titanium mobile

Tags: audio, titanium, audio-recording, titanium-mobile

I have used kitchensink audio recording .But it plays recording too much low after saving audio file as caf format.Is there any way to record audio with high audibility and quality in titanium mobile?

Please Suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'MP4' file format for the compression to make high quality audio recording.

```
var recording = Ti.Media.createAudioRecorder();
recording.compression = Titanium.Media.AUDIO_FILEFORMAT_MP4;
```